# Any good open source functional testing tool for java based Web Application

Tags: automated-testing, web-application, regression-testing

Any good open source functional testing tool for java based Web Application Regression Testing
which require less coding effort 
Except Selenium

Our Web application is only run in Google Chrome.

Comment: Do you mean that Selenium is not an option for you?

Comment: Do you mean that your web application is java-based i.e. running in an applet? Or do you want the testing tool to be java-based?

Comment: Less coding effort compared to what?

Comment: Selenium is simply a browser automation tool with many flavors (often used for all things functional and ui testing).  Can you describe exactly what kind of "web application regression testing" you want to accomplish and what difficulties you have with selenium? And which selenium: Selenium2, WebDriver, or Remote Control you are referring to?

Comment: Have you researched [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) at all?

Comment: Welcome to SQA, user5320. Could you elaborate on what your criteria are? All we have right now is "like Selenium but with less coding".

Comment: Or is the server code developed in java but is HTML in the client?

Answer (score 1):

(do you mean really open source or freeware? If you don't like to code, why would you need opensource?)

Selenium IDE (not the same as Selenium 2 or Selenium WebDriver) or my old buddy [BadBoy](http://badboy.com.au)
 are just two examples of free software.

Comment: I suspect by open source, the OP really means "I don't have to pay for it". It may also mean "I need to verify there is no phoning home", as I've worked in shops (government) that required this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for your ans... m using Selenium webdriver.this is better than RC but too many things to be implemented

Comment: look for Seleinuum *IDE*, it is neither WebDriver nor RC.